# How to add GPU computation for the CIFAR 10 pytorch Tutorial?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, computer-vision, gpu, pytorch

The cifar 10 tutorial for pytorch can be found here:
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-beginner-blitz-cifar10-tutorial-py

The tutorial goes through how to use pytorch to make a simple convolutional neural network for the CIFAR 10 dataset. Near the end, it slightly goes through how to implement the above code for GPU.

Essentially the difference is that we create the device =torch.device('gpu') and send all the tensors to the gpu device before computing with them. So essentially, we want the net object and the input and labels tensors to be sent to the gpu device before doing the computations each time.

So I went back and added:

```
net.to(device)
```

And in the loop of computation:

```
with torch.no_grad():
    for data in testloader:
        images, labels = data
        #I added this line of change:
        inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)
        outputs = net(images)
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)
        c = (predicted == labels).squeeze()
        for i in range(4):
            label = labels[i]
            class_correct[label] += c[i].item()
            class_total[label] += 1
```

However, this caused an error: `OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory`

What am i misunderstanding? Do I need to make any other changes so the whole tutorial can work for GPU?

Comment: Does your gpu have enough memory?

Comment: Oh is that the problem? Do I need to remove the tensor once I've sent it to the gpu to save space? How do i do that?

Comment: I don't think it's GPU memory that's causing the problem here, the python process can not allocated RAM memory. If he ran out of GPU memory then it would be a RuntimeError.

Comment: @wawawewa can you check how the amount of RAM is changing using `htop` program and can you also add how much RAM do you have ? I ran this tutorial on a 8 GB machine with no issues.

Comment: Running Htop before even running the script and the top left says 4.20/7.01 GB Mem. But Shouldn't there be a seperate few GB of RAM onboard the GPU? Btw my GPU is Nvidia GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti] with CUDA 10 toolkit

Comment: To be clear, I can run the tutorial just fine myself when im just using cpu. It's only when im trying to use GPU and make the above changes that I run into problems.

Comment: In which line does the error happen? Also, are you able to run any other PyTorch code on GPU? This is to rule out driver/cuda config issues.

Comment: in the chunk of code where we loop over the dataset multiple times.

Comment: This is not an issue with GPU RAM but rather an issue with your host RAM.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen when there is not enough swap space. Try with small number of `num_workers`.

Hope this helps!